Por no me muestra el gif?
Estoy haciendo una proyecto nuevo con maven, pero no me carga el gif que quiero poner en que me estoy equivocando?
Este es el código con el que cargo la imagen:
private void runGif()
{
    try
    {
        InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("\\com\\nuro_chemicals\\Views\\Img\\experiment_lab.gif");
        
        if(input != null)
        {
            byte[] gif = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
        
            Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(gif);
            lbl_Gif.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        }
        
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, 
                                      "No se pudo cargar la imagen correctamente!!", 
                                      "Nuro Chemicals", 
                                      JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                                      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

Intente poner el gif directamente desde el diseñador, pero en ese caso solo me muestra la imagen estática, y no la animación como tal.
El código solo me muestra el jFrame como lo muestro en la siguiente imagen:

La ruta no creo que sea, ya cheque y la ruta esta escrita correctamente, también ya intente con esta / y obtengo el mismo resultado de la imagen.

Probaste meter el ImageIcon dentro de un JLabel?

Lo estoy metiendo en un JLabel, es este: lbl_Gif

El problema probablemente radica en la forma en que estás intentando cargar la imagen en tu proyecto. En Maven, los recursos deben estar en la estructura de directorios correcta para que se carguen correctamente.
En tu código, estás utilizando getClass().getResourceAsStream("\com\nuro_chemicals\Views\Img\experiment_lab.gif") para obtener la imagen. Asegúrate de que la ruta sea la correcta y de que el archivo GIF esté ubicado en el directorio de recursos adecuado.
Una forma más segura de cargar recursos es utilizando rutas relativas, por ejemplo: getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Img/experiment_lab.gif"). Esto asume que el directorio "Img" está en el directorio de recursos del proyecto.
Verifica la estructura de directorios de tu proyecto Maven y ajusta la ruta de carga de la imagen en consecuencia para resolver el problema de carga del GIF.

Ya lo pude resolver, mi error era que la imagen la tenia en el paquete de Java, por lo tanto no podía encontrar la imagen, ya que la tenía que poner en el paquete de resources
